# Convert PNG to a binary (base 2) string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, binary, file-handling

I Basically want to read a png file and convert it into binary(base 2) and store the converted base 2 value in a string. I've tried so many things, but all of them are showing some error

Comment: Please show the code, the error message and explain what you have done. We cannot help you with code we cannot see.

Comment: There are numerous libraries to read a PNG file, and I think all of them support converting to a string of bytes.  Converting bytes to binary should be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two approaches:

1. At first, try to read the image and decode it into base64 format:

   ```
    import base64

    with open("my_image.png", "rb") as f:
        png_encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read())
   ```

   Then, you encode base64 string into base2 string:

   ```
    encoded_b2 = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in png_encoded])

    print(encoded_b2)
   ```

   Although, you may decode base2 string into png file:

   ```
    decoded_b64 = b"".join([bytes(chr(int(encoded_b2[i:i + 8], 2)), "utf-8") for i in range(0, len(encoded_b2), 8)])

    with open('my_image_decoded.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(decoded_b64))
   ```
2. At second, read bytes directly and write byte as base 2 number into string:

   ```
    from PIL import Image
    from io import BytesIO


    out = BytesIO()

    with Image.open("my_image.png") as img:
        img.save(out, format="png")

    image_in_bytes = out.getvalue()

    encoded_b2 = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in image_in_bytes])
    print(encoded_b2)
   ```

   And you may decode base2 string into file:

   ```
    decoded_b2 = [int(encoded_b2[i:i + 8], 2) for i in range(0, len(encoded_b2), 8)]

    with open('my_image_decoded.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(bytes(decoded_b2))
   ```